# Regex to match numbers regardless of seperators

Tags: regex

I need a regex to match the following:

Any 6 to 16 numbers inside a text even if they are not consecutive.

eg:

1. **abc123sadas456** should match **123sadas456**
2. **123$3123asbaasd4** should match **123$3123asbaasd4**
3. **1234as2** should not match (minimum 6 numbers)
4. **12345678asd** should match **12345678**

Thank you

Comment: The question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt) to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and take the tour.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It's just a regex. Nothing to show here. I have been trying to do this one for the past 2 days. Not sure what effort I should show.. Very weird to down vote

Answer (score 0):

Does this help? Python.

```
import re
list =["abc123sadas456","123$3123asbaasd4","1234as2", 12345678]

for line in list:
    nr = len(re.sub(r"[\D]", '', str(line)))
    if (nr >=6 and nr < 17):
        print("MATCH:", line)
    else:
        print("NO MATCH:", line)
```

Comment: thanks @Xenobiologist. I already did the same using java. I was hoping i could find a regex that could match it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution later.

```
\d([a-zA-Z.\_\\+\-*\.\%$]*\d){5,15}
```

**Note:** This regex will match digits even if they are separated by any character. Add or remove characters from the middle list as needed.